# Como acessar uma lista que está dentro de outra lista em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista que possui dentro dela outra lista com o nome dos alunos, e mais uma lista que foi dividida em mais duas listas, representando a primeira nota e a segunda nota. Por exemplo:

```
[['Matheus', 'Julia', 'Eduardo'], [[9.4, 4.7, 3.2], [7.2, 8.3, 2.4]]]
```

Gostaria de saber o que eu faço para acessar cada nível dessa lista, para retornar separadamente o nome dos alunos, a sua primeira nota e a segunda nota.
Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
nome = []
nota1 = []
nota2 = []

for i in range(0, 3):
   nome.append(str(input('Nome do Aluno: ')))
   nota1.append(float(input('Nota 1: ')))
   nota2.append(float(input('Nota 2: ')))
   print('\n')

notas = []
notas.append(nota1)
notas.append(nota2)

listaAlunos = []
listaAlunos.append(nome)
listaAlunos.append(notas)

for i in range(0, len(listaAlunos)):
   for j in range(0, 3):
      print(listaAlunos[i][j])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem forma melhores de armazenar seus dados como lista de dicionários, ou lista de namedtuple. Se o modelo de aluno fosse mais complexo, ainda teria a lista de classes definidas pelo programador.

Mas primeiro...

### Respondendo à pergunta

```
listaAlunos = [['Matheus', 'Julia', 'Eduardo'], [[9.4, 4.7, 3.2], [7.2, 8.3, 2.4]]]

alunos, notas = listaAlunos

for i in range(len(alunos)):
    print(f"Aluno: {alunos[i]}")
    for n, notaAluno in enumerate(notas):
        print(f"Nota {n+1}: {notaAluno[i]}")
```

## Outras opções

### Lista de dicionários

A forma de armazenamento seria

```
listaAlunos = []

for i in range(0, 3):
   nome = input('Nome do Aluno: ')
   nota1 = float(input('Nota 1: '))
   nota2 = float(input('Nota 2: '))
   listaAlunos.append({"aluno": nome, "nota1": nota1, "nota2": nota2})
   print('\n')
```

Teríamos como valor

```
[{'aluno': 'Matheus', 'nota1': 9.4, 'nota2': 7.2}, 
 {'aluno': 'Julia', 'nota1': 4.7, 'nota2': 8.3}, 
 {'aluno': 'Eduardo', 'nota1': 3.2, 'nota2': 2.4}
]
```

Para imprimir

```
for aluno in listaAlunos:
    print(f"Aluno: {aluno['aluno']}")
    print(f"Nota 1: {aluno['nota1']}")
    print(f"Nota 2: {aluno['nota2']}")
    print()
```

A saída seria:

```
Aluno: Matheus
Nota 1: 9.4
Nota 2: 7.2

Aluno: Julia
Nota 1: 4.7
Nota 2: 8.3

Aluno: Eduardo
Nota 1: 3.2
Nota 2: 2.4
```

### Lista de namedtuple

Coleta

```
from collections import namedtuple

listaAlunos = []

Aluno = namedtuple("Aluno", "aluno nota1 nota2")

for i in range(0, 3):
   nome = input('Nome do Aluno: ')
   nota1 = float(input('Nota 1: '))
   nota2 = float(input('Nota 2: '))
   listaAlunos.append(Aluno(aluno=nome, nota1=nota1, nota2=nota2))
   print('\n')
```

Dados armazenados

```
[Aluno(aluno='Matheus', nota1=9.4, nota2=7.2),
 Aluno(aluno='Julia', nota1=4.7, nota2=8.3), 
 Aluno(aluno='Eduardo', nota1=3.2, nota2=2.4)
]
```

Para imprimir

```
for aluno in listaAlunos:
    print(f"Aluno : {aluno.aluno}")
    print(f"Nota 1: {aluno.nota1}")
    print(f"Nota 2: {aluno.nota2}")
```

A saída seria a mesma de antes.

Outra possibilidade seria armazenar em dicionário, onde a chave fosse o nome do aluno. A estrutura ficadia assim:

```
{
 "Matheus": {
             "nota1": 9.4,
             "nota2": 7.2
            },
 "Julia": {
           "nota1": 4.7,
           "nota2": 8.3
          },
 "Eduardo": {
             "nota1": 3.2,
             "nota2": 2.4
            }
}
```

Essa também é viável, porém pode complicar caso você queira listar os alunos com nota 1 menor que 5, por exemplo

Para este caso a estrutura de lista contendo dicionários é a mais adequada, pois você pode usar o `filter`

De forma simplificada teríamos:

```
listaAlunos = [{'aluno': 'Matheus', 'nota1': 9.4, 'nota2': 7.2}, {'aluno': 'Julia', 'nota1': 4.7, 'nota2': 8.3}, {'aluno': 'Eduardo', 'nota1': 3.2, 'nota2': 2.4}]

for aluno in filter(lambda aluno: aluno["nota1"] > 5, listaAlunos):
    print(aluno)
```

Sendo o resultado:

```
{'aluno': 'Matheus', 'nota1': 9.4, 'nota2': 7.2}
```

No caso acima, `lambda` pode ser substituída por uma função

```
def nota1_maior_que_cinco(aluno):
    return aluno["nota1"] > 5

for aluno in filter(nota1_maior_que_cinco, listaAlunos):
    print(aluno)
{'aluno': 'Matheus', 'nota1': 9.4, 'nota2': 7.2}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, ainda estou na parte de listas sobre listas e esse exercício so podia ser feito usando estes conhecimentos. Mas já estou analisando essa parte de dicionários e namedtuple que você mandou para compreender melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia armazenar de outra forma como dicionário por exemplo, mas segue uma possível resposta para lista dentro de lista:

```
for i, aluno in enumerate(listaAlunos[0]):
    print(aluno)
    print(f'nota 1 - {listaAlunos[1][0][i]}')
    print(f'nota 2 - {listaAlunos[1][1][i]}')
```

O enumerate gera um 'contador' e podemos utilizar como índice no vetor.

Entrada:

```
Nome do Aluno: maria
Nota 1: 10
Nota 2: 20

Nome do Aluno: josé
Nota 1: 23
Nota 2: 24

Nome do Aluno: moises
Nota 1: 23
Nota 2: 45

Nome do Aluno: matusalem
Nota 1: 34
Nota 2: 45
```

Saída:

```
maria
nota 1 - 10.0
nota 2 - 20.0
josé
nota 1 - 23.0
nota 2 - 24.0
moises
nota 1 - 23.0
nota 2 - 45.0
matusalem
nota 1 - 34.0
nota 2 - 45.0
```

Comment: Ainda não estudei a parte de dicionários, e nesse exercício o professor quer que use os conhecimentos de listas dentro de listas.

Comment: Poderia me explicar porque você colocou dentro do enumarate listaAlunos[0]?

Comment: Você usou listaAlunos[0] no enumarate porque a quantidade de índice já serve para os demais elementos?

Comment: Fala Matheus, boa tarde! coloquei listaAlunos[0] pois este é o indice dos alunos na sua lista de listas. Fazendo listaAlunos[0] tenho os nomes dos alunos, e assim consigo iterar sobre eles. Já listaAlunos[1][0] tenho as primeiras notas e listaAlunos[1][1] temos a segunda nota, movimentamos pelos dados utilizando o indice i. Abraço!

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda cara! Você não faz ideia de como eu consigo entender esse problema e os outros que eu estava tentando resolver.

Comment: Por nada, qualquer coisa estamos ai! Abraço!

Comment: Uma vez que você deveria usar apenas listas, pense em uma estrutura parecida com a da lista de dicionários. Use, por exemplo: `[ ['Matheus", 9.4, 7.2 ], ["Julia", 4.7 , 8.3], ..... ]` . Essa estrutura é mais `clean` uma vez que os dados dos objetos (alunos) estão contidos em uma estrutura e não espalhados. Isso também ajudará com a recuperação dos dados e você poderá usar o `filter` conforme descrito.